# Is there anyway to fill up the boot screen on Touch Bar when booting up?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I was wondering if there's a modification on Touch Bar when a MBP booting up e.g. putting up a JPG image before booting completed / login.

Answer (score 1):

Touch Bar is not designed to be modified by the end user, so while it might theoretically be possible to do this, there is no such modification currently available as this is designed to be a secure part of your computers hardware.